# SSL unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have found other posts with this error on code side and some that give some workarounds that in theory should work for the package manager but none seem to work.

I have had NPM working previously and I'm not sure what changed recently that broke it.

I'm trying to install better-sqlite3 in this instance.

request to https://registry.npmjs.org/better-sqlite3 failed, reason: write EPROTO 7C720000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:908:

My initial thought on seeing this was to disable strict-ssl, which I know isn't best option, but is the one I was aware of. That didn't fix the issue.

I've also tried exporting random (becuase I don't know which to pick and there are 3 of them) root certificates for my company from chrome into a folder and then adding npm config set cafile path/to/file but that doesn't seem to work

I've also tried NODE_OPTIONS=--tls-min-v1.0
and NODE_OPTIONS=--use-openssl-ca

I know I'm going to get a lot of not-great options that aren't secure, and I'd rather go with secure options, but the directions provided are frequently not clear to me, maybe because I lack some knowledge about these utilities that others have.

I can get to everywhere via my browser, is there anyway to manually download materials and cache it somewhere for npm? This can be helpful in some situations as well, but I have no idea how to do it.

Latest error (along with what is successful).  This is after I used openssl command to find the certificate actually being pulled back, and then adding that to the npm configuration (both global and user).

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rc 70373ms (cache stale)
npm verb type system
npm verb stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist failed, reason: write EPROTO 08840000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:908:
npm verb stack
npm verb stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nvm\v19.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
npm verb stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm verb stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:488:9)
npm verb stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
npm verb stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
npm verb stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
npm verb stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
npm verb cwd c:\BitBucket\test
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm verb node v19.0.0
npm verb npm  v9.1.1
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist failed, reason: write EPROTO 08840000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:908:
npm ERR!
```

After spending my entire evening up to 1 AM on this I was able to get npm itself working by cleaning out all of my settings for npm and then re-setting each of them, strict-ssl false is back now, the certificate is set also, but since not everything would work right with it I had to do strict-ssl false anyway :/

I had to add my proxy settings back even though I think in theory it's not supposed to be needed because I could fetch some things without it set, but apparently not everything.

Now, the only issue I'm having is with node-gyp.  Everything else can pull packages with current config, curl, npm, I even added yarn and got it working, but node-gyp consistently errors out with this inane error

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v19.0.0/node-v19.0.0-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

So infuriating.

Comment: It does this even when I've disabled certificate verification with NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 set.  But I can ping registry.npmjs.org and get return packets from what looks correct, 104.16.23.35 (cross-checking with https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/)

Even after I set it to use the http version of the page it's not using that registry, whether I set it as global or not. It's so weird.

Comment: I used this command after I figured out how to get to it (was installed under my gitfolder) openssl s_client -host registry.npmjs.org -port 443 and it retrieves the cert that my company servers are presenting. It looks like it may be working better with this , as I got further than before

Now I'm failing after it downloads more of the packages due to SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Comment: npm verb cwd c:\BitBucket\test
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm verb node v19.0.0
npm verb npm  v9.1.1
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expand-template failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
npm verb exit 1
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify 1668038595825
npm verb unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1668038595827
npm verb code 1

Comment: I'm able to get it to download several packages now, but it gets stuck on minimist

Comment: Maybe I can work around this with the certificates?  The problem is I am just trying to get just yarn by itself to work without strict-ssl turned off and no matter what certificate I'm sticking in the file it's pointing to it seems not to work.

And then there is the whole matter of whether it should be cafile or caFilePath and blah blah... I know strict-ssl worked even though I was reading one place it should be enableStrictSSL=false instead. My head is swimming with all this mess.

Comment: I have a similar problem when connecting to an api

Comment: This doesn't pertain to the api usage, but for package management error apparently we have an internal registry that I needed to add to get around this issues.

Comment: Yes, it's not the same but overall it is a connection / handshake error. So, I ended up fixing it by forcing TLSv1.3 connection. Maybe that can help you or give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an internal repository/mirror setup within my company, so unfortunately the answer here won't apply for others, but all I had to do was retain my strict-ssl false type of settings and setup their repository.

Comment: What do you mean an in internal repo/mirror? Do you mean an internal mirror to the NPM registry, and did you set that as the registry to use in your global conf?

Comment: Yes, I think it's an internal mirror or cache of the NPM registry.  This said, since I wrote this, I've had periodic issues even with these settings working for every package. It worked on 11/14, but then recently I was getting node-gyp errors mentioning the self-signed certificate. It's not the same error as above but I still have had hiccups and had to switch versions of node to get things to work. 

Base npm is working fine, it's just when I need node-gyp this has been a pain.

Comment: Disable my work VPN helped